# How can I re{duce,move} the Angry Fruit Salad effect

Tags: colors, filter

[image]

Above, you can see the output of the `kscreen-doctor -o` command on Suse Tumbleweed.

I tried `kscreen-doctor -o | cat` to no avail.

Short of using a black background as a damage limiting device (still Angry Fruit Salad, but at least I can read the text), what can I do to remove the garish colors from the output?

NB I have used `kscreen doctor` as an example, but there are other culprits as well. E.g., `apt` in Debian uses a bright yellow to output info during downloading, and to change the color one of the developers suggested to use A LITERAL ESCAPE CHARACTER in Apt's global configuration file

Comment: Do you want _no_ colors or _better_ colors? I suspect this might be using your `$LS_COLORS` variable, have you tried changing that to see if you can get a color palette that is more to your liking? I get a much nicer output on my system and it looks like it's using my LS_COLORS. See [Terminator custom colors overriden by KDE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/167947) for help on changing it.

Comment: Hmm no, actually, I think `LS_COLORS` is irrelevant. The colors seem to be hardcoded in the source code: https://github.com/KDE/libkscreen/blob/master/src/doctor/doctor.cpp

Comment: @terdon _"Do you want no colors or better colors?"_ No colors.\n Restricting the conversation to `kscreen-doctor`: ① what is wrong with `xrandr`? ② it seems that the developers used colors as a POOR substitute of a proper formatting (e.g., `xrandr` ) and ③ why hardcoded the colors? (e.g., IPython console has the `%color LightBg` magic).

Answer (score -2):

I use RHEL/CentOS 7 and 8, and in those I...

- edit `/etc/profile.d/colorls.sh`

  - bottom of file which has `alias ls color=auto` for all color instances I change *auto* to *none*
  - this will turn off coloring in the terminal window
- in your home account create a `~/.vimrc` file

  - with the line containing `syntax none`
  - this will turn off coloring when using `vim` *which I also despise*

The only coloring I do like is the prompt, or certain parts of the prompt.  Especially having the prompt red when root.  See here to do prompt color:

[red terminal font when root](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551017/red-terminal-font-when-root)

that is my standard practice, to have the plain black window with only white letters and no fruit salad.  In SUSE/SLES I do not know if they use the `/etc/profile.d` convention; if not I think you just want to change the `alias ls` from having some `color=` content.

... assuming your fruit salad output is not directly caused by your use of `kscreen-doctor`, an app which I am not familiar with.  I have written basic C code where I print characters in a certain color when desired, like a green OK using `\033[32m` (which I believe is an escape sequence?) so if kscreen-doctor does something like that that then I'm not sure how to undo that effect outside of that program.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144466/discussion-between-terdon-and-ron).